# Why this false condition returns true?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why when I write on the last input 6 instead of 60 and click on the button, it returns true even though my condition is false?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button>get
      result</button>
    <div></div>
    <input Class="value1" value=10>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input Class="value2" value=20>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input Class="value3" value=30>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input Class="value4" value=40>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input Class="value5" value=50>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input Class="value6" value=60>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('button').click(function() {
        var value1 = $(".value1").val();
        var value2 = $(".value2").val();
        var value3 = $(".value3").val();
        var value4 = $(".value4").val();
        var value5 = $(".value5").val();
        var value6 = $(".value6").val();

        if (value1 < value2 && value2 < value3 && value3 < value4 && value4 < value5 && value5 < value6) {

          $("div").text("true");
        } else {

          $("div").text("false");
        }

      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are comparing strings (from `.value`), not numbers.

Comment: So how can i manage can you correct my code please m?

Comment: you could take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) in front of the value and convert them to a number.

Comment: If you can manage my code i will thank you a lot, if not also thanks for your helping

Comment: Also, remember to always wrap attribute values with quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your issue is convert the input box to be of type "Number", to limit the characters inputted, then convert all variables to Number.

For example:

```
<input  Class="value3" type="number" value=30>

$('button').click(function() {
    var value1 = Number($(".value1").val());
    var value2 = Number($(".value2").val());
    var value3 = Number($(".value3").val());
    var value4 = Number($(".value4").val());
    var value5 = Number($(".value5").val());
    var value6 = Number($(".value6").val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works perfectly, thanks from the deep of my heart

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings (from .value), not numbers.

---

You could utilise a loop with the converted values with [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), like

```
let isIncreasing = true
let i = 1
while (i < 6 && isIncreasing) {
    isIncreasing = +$(".value" + i).val() < +$(".value" + (++i)).val();
}

if (isIncreasing) $("div").text("true");
else $("div").text("false");
```

Comment: Thanks sister for your helping you're great but i found the first answer of imvai2 very easy to your because i'm a beginner.. So thanks an other time for your time trying helping me.

Answer (score 0):

By default your input value is numeric (input=30), but when you change value in your input, that become string value, and there are not implicit converstion of string to numeric.

When you get numeric value of input, use parse function like Number or parseInt